# setting $rootScope but is not reflected in ng-src

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework 1 in my development. What i intend to achieve is to update the profile image of the same view after user successfully upload image. My code is as follow:

```
<img ng-src="{{ $root.user.userImageUrl }}">
```

This is a service:

```
fileTransfer.upload(image, url, function (res) {
    $cordovaDialogs.alert('Update image success', 'Success').then(function () {
        $rootScope.user.userImageUrl = res;
        console.log($rootScope.user.userImageUrl);
    })
});
```

I am pretty sure the code i wrote is correct as it do reflect the new image uploaded by user successfully if `$rootScope.user.userImageUrl` is not a valid image link at first.
However, if `$rootScope.user.imageUrl` has a valid image link to display at first, the image of the same view wont be updated (meaning the old image is still retain in the view)

I am not sure what the problem is, as i did a mock in fiddle it works. Could it be something related to ionic view?
I even apply `$rootScope.$apply()` but what i got is digest already applied.

[Link to mock example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8445/)

Answer (score 0):

The mock you attached works like a charm with a minor edit.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8446/

All I can think of is try to wrap it in a timeout:

```
fileTransfer.upload(image, url, function (res) {
    $cordovaDialogs.alert('Update image success', 'Success').then(function () {
     $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.user.userImageUrl = res;
        console.log($rootScope.user.userImageUrl);
     });
    })
});
```

Comment: will be testing this, but could you explain why timeout is required? wasnt it suppose to be asynchronous after a deferred callback?

Comment: In my updated mock it works right out of the box without any timeout. I just figured due to using ionic it might be required to force redraw, timeout would wrap the assignment in $apply block and force the watchers to fire.

Comment: well, i tried it both with $rootScope.apply() and without. Both still does not change the image. However, with the $timeout applied, the $digest error message has disappeared. But it still doesn't change the fact that original image is still being retained.